# Add Jquery object as key to another object

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can I add Jquery Object to the blank object as key. For example:-

```
var obj = {};//blank object

var myId = $("#myId");//jQuery Object
var myId2 = $("#myId2");//another jQuery Object

obj[myId] = "Trying to add myId as a key";
obj[myId2] = "Trying to add myId2 as a key";
```

But the output of the obj contains only one key. Is the above thing is possible in JS or not?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Javascript converts array keys to strings.

Comment: Why do you need this? Can you give us more information about what are you trying to do?

Comment: @DCoder So in the above code it is converting the keys to string. But why it is not adding both of the object as keyn in object.

Comment: Because `$('#myId').toString()` produces `"[object Object]"`, and `$('#myId2').toString()` also produces `"[object Object]"`. How do you expect to differentiate between them? Just like running `obj = {}; obj.foo = 1; obj.foo = 2;` and asking why you only get one key.

Comment: @Johnツ I want to keep the reference of the element and it's inline style attribute. So that I will be able to restore it's inline style back to original.

Comment: alert($('div').toString() === $('input').toString()) => true

Why not use `obj = {'#myId': $('#myId'), '#myId2': $('#myId2')};`

Comment: If you want to cache them do you mean; `obj[myId[0].id] = myId; obj[myId2[0].id] = myId2 ... obj["myId"].css(..) ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep the reference to object you can use an array of objects instead of an object:

```
[
   {
      "jQueryElement": myId1,
      "note": "Trying to add myId as a key"
   },
   {
      "jQueryElement": myId2,
      "note": "Trying to add myId2 as a key"
   }
]
```

Then you will be able to do:

```
function getNoteOfJqueryObj(element) {
 element = $(element);
 for (var i in array) {
     if (array[i].jQueryElement[0] == element[0]) {
         return array[i].note;
     }
 }
 return undefined;
}
```

I guess that this is one of the best ways you can choose.

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lbvxp/)

Answer (score 2):

You have to use a string as property name (e.g. the id of the jquery object?).

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects